# Spark ML ALS collaborative filtering input dataset requirements

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

When using spark's ml ALS for collaborative filtering should I use existing ratings only or produce whole factorization matrix filling in 0 for non-existing ratings?

i.e.

```
           prod1    prod2    prod3
user1        .5       x      .3   
user2         x      .2      .2   
user3        .1       x       x
```

for the example above input ratings should be existing one or the whole matrix

Answer (score 0):

### Implicit feedback

There is no reason to add artificial ratings because it doesn't bring any additional information.

### Explicit feedback

You shouldn't add artificial ratings because 0 score is not neutral and it will affect the results.